# How can I stop tag separation in VSCODE using react?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

After saving changes, tags are being separated like this.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return ( < div >
    Hello!
    <
    /div> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Go to settings >> extensions >> prettier and configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code formatter is not correctly set up. You can either disable `Format on Save` or correctly setup your code formatter.

## 1. Disable `Format on Save`

[image]

## 2. Correctly setup your code formatter

I like using [Prettier](https://prettier.io) as it is fairly simple to set up and helps you keep code neat with almost no previously defined rules.

Here's a [guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/how-to-use-prettier-vscode) you can follow to set it up.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Have a great day:)